# How to compute $P(Z_2 \le Z_3 \le Z_4| Z_2=Z_1 )$? where we have an i.i.d. sequence of standard normal $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,Z_4$.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Suppose that we have an i.i.d. sequence of standard normal $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,Z_4$. How to compute
\begin{align}
P(Z_2 \le Z_3 \le Z_4| Z_2=Z_1 )
\end{align}

**My idea**

\begin{align}
P(Z_2 \le Z_3 \le Z_4| Z_2=Z_1 ) =P( Z_1 \le Z_3 \le Z_4 ) =\frac{1}{3!}
\end{align}
The last step follow because there are $3!$ ways that arrange $Z_1,Z_3,Z_4$ and normal is symmetric.
However, I am not sure if the second step is fine and we can drop the conditioning?

Comment: I suspect that's not OK, and that the probability distribution of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, conditioned on their being equal, is that of a normal distribution with the same mean as originally, but with a smaller variance by a factor of $2$.  But I haven't thought about it deeply.

Comment: @BrianTung Can you elaborate more on the variance being smaller by a factor of 2?

Comment: If you take the PDF of the bivariate normal distribution (take the standard normal distribution for simplicity's sake), then condition along the diagonal (where the two variables are equal), I think you'll see that the variance drops by a factor of $2$—the exponent of $e$ goes from $-x^2/2$ in the univariate case to $-x^2$, equivalent to the variance $\sigma^2$ going from $1$ to $2$.

Comment: Sorry, correction: going from $1$ to $1/2$.

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks. Do you think we can compute it exactly?

Comment: Hmm...I will have to think about that.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer that is too long for a comment:

---

Consider the joint distribution of $(Z_1-Z_2, Z_2)$. This is a bivariate normal distribution with means $0$ and $0$, variances $2$ and $1$, and correlation $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Thus it has the same distribution as $(2U, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} U +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} V)$ where $U$ and $V$ are i.i.d. standard normal. (You can verify this by checking that the means, variances, and correlation are the same.)

So, the conditional distribution of $Z_2$ given $Z_1=Z_2$ is the same as the conditional distribution of $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} U + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} V$ given $2U=0$. By plugging in $U=0$, we immediately see that the conditional distribution is $N(0, 1/2)$, as Brian Tung mentioned in the comments.

---

Thus you can rewrite your original probability as
$$P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}V \le Z_3 \le Z_4)$$
where $V, Z_3, Z_4$ are i.i.d. standard normal. Some sort of volume/symmetry argument might allow you to compute this, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more direct approach. Let $E=\{Z_1=Z_2\}$ and $h(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$. Notice $(Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,Z_4)\sim f$ where $$f(x,y,z,w)=h(x)h(y)h(z)h(w)$$ The conditional distribution of $(Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,Z_4)$ given $E$, denoted by $f_{E}$, equals $$f_{E}(z_2,z_3,z_4)=\frac{f(z_2,z_2,z_3,z_4)\sqrt{2}}{\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}f(z_2,z_2,z_3,z_4)\sqrt{2}dz_4dz_3dz_2}$$ The probability you're trying to compute is $$P(Z_2 \leq Z_3 \leq Z_4|Z_1=Z_2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{z_2}^{\infty} \int_{z_3}^{\infty} f_{E}(z_2,z_3,z_4)dz_4dz_3dz_2$$ This is approximately 15.2%

**Remark**: The $\sqrt{2}$ represents the "surface area component" for the parametric surface $\vec{r}(u,v,w)=(u,u,v,w)$ whose trace is $$\Big\{(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)\in \mathbb{R}^4\Big|z_1=z_2\Big\}$$

Comment: Can you give any intuition as to why this should be less than the naive answer of 1/6 ~ 0.167? Thanks.

Comment: @Benjamin Wang I would read the comment above provided by Brian Tung to see why this is the case.

Comment: Thank you. It's still not obvious though. Because reducing the variance doesn't seem to break symmetry

Comment: I interpreted his comment as suggesting that the conditional pdf is more focused around the origin and less focused on the "outskirts." If you're putting more emphasis of the distribution around the origin then this, by the nature of the region of space over which we're integrating, will lead to a net decrease in likelihood.

Comment: Sure. It's more centered, and we're integrating over a hyper plane . Still don't understand why it matters though. Perhaps a more trivial example would be better for intuition?

Comment: Have you tried to envision the region of space $\{(x,y,z):x\leq y\leq z\}$? If you can envision this region you'll immediately see what's going on. Not much of this region is "near" the origin.